# Is there a way to show a "console selection menu" for user input in my script like Ctrl+Space in PSReadLine

Tags: powershell-core

PSReadLine has **FANTASTIC** functionality for it's **Ctrl+Space** key binding.

[image]

Is there a way that I can use this same "console menu" functionality for letting my script users (usually me) select from a list of possible values? I don't want to have a separate grid view (`Out-GridView`) to make the selection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using advanced functions is one of the common ways to achieve this and if you want to have dynamic path completion (as per your comment) then this capability can be added with `Register-ArgumentCompleter`

```
$scriptBlock = {
    param($commandName, $parameterName, $wordToComplete, $commandAst, $fakeBoundParameters)

    Get-ChildItem -Path $pwd -Directory | Where-Object {
        $_ -like "*$wordToComplete*"
    } | ForEach-Object {
        "'$_'"
    }
}
#Register the above scriptblock to the foo function Path Parameter
Register-ArgumentCompleter -CommandName foo -ParameterName Path -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock

function foo { 
    param( 
        [ValidateSet("Tom","Dick","Jane")] 
        $Name,
        [ValidateRange(21, 65)] 
        $Age,
        [string] 
        $Path 
    ) 
    Write-Host ($Name + $Age + $Path)
}
```

More information can be found with `Get-Help about_Functions_Advanced`

The above also works with partial directory names, for example if you know the directory has "test" in the name type `foo -path test` and press CTRL+Space, you'll get a filtered list - pretty cool, right?

Give it a try

Comment: Is there a way to make the set that is validated a dynamic set? Say I want to display the directories under $pwd and choose on, but I want it to allow me to select new directories when they're created w/o needing to change the script source.

Comment: @JoshGust updated with a dynamic example, hope it helps